# How do I set convertHighWaterMarkToRowVersion on the indexer parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search, indexer, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to set the "convertHighWaterMarkToRowVersion" configuration setting on my search indexer as per this documentation but can't figure out how to do this using the Azure Search SDK in C#.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#converthighwatermarktorowversion

I can see that there is a property called IndexingParameterConfiguration as part of the IndexingParameters object but everything I tried doesn't seem to work and I can't find any examples.

```
var parameters = new IndexingParameters()
{
    BatchSize = 100,
    MaxFailedItems = 0,
    MaxFailedItemsPerBatch = 0,
    IndexingParametersConfiguration = ?
};

var indexer = new SearchIndexer(indexerName, dataSource.Name, searchIndex.Name)
{
    Description = "Indexer configured to crawl " + searchIndex.Name,
    Parameters = parameters                
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? I don't see "IndexingParametersConfiguration" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexingparameters?view=azure-dotnet (but there is "Configuration")

Comment: That one is v10.1. I'm using Azure.Search.Documents v11.3.0 (latest, found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.indexingparameters?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convertHighWaterMarkToRowVersion` is an uncommon setting that doesn't have a setter/getter, so you'll need to explicitly set it by key.

```
var config = new IndexingParametersConfiguration();
config["convertHighWaterMarkToRowVersion"] = true;

var parameters = new IndexingParameters()
{
    BatchSize = 100,
    MaxFailedItems = 0,
    MaxFailedItemsPerBatch = 0,
    IndexingParametersConfiguration = config
};

var indexer = new SearchIndexer(indexerName, dataSource.Name, searchIndex.Name)
{
    Description = "Indexer configured to crawl " + searchIndex.Name,
    Parameters = parameters                
};
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay! I managed to validate that this worked by calling the List Indexers operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/list-indexers